# SQL Round if numerical?

Tags: sql, sql-server

(Beginner at sql)

I've been getting the error

```
'Error converting data type nvarchar to float.'
```

Which is because I was trying to round an nvarchar(10) column with both characters and integers, and obviously it can't round the characters. (I can't make two separate columns with different data types as they both need to be in this column)

I'm looking for a way to round the numbers in the nvarchar column whilst also returning the characters

I've being trying CAST/Converts nothing seems to work

I've also tried

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Tbl1.Column1) = 1
THEN    cast(Round(Tbl1.Column1, 0) AS float)
ELSE Tbl1.Column1 END   AS 'Column1'
```

in the select statement

I cant figure out what else will solve this!

Sample Data in this column would be

```
 8.1
 2
 9.0
 9.6
 A
 -
 5.3
 D
 E
 5.1
 -
```

Comment: IsNumeric is not really safe here. It returns a lot of false positives. And you will have to convert the rounded value to varchar because you can't mix datatypes in a single column.

Comment: What's the goal with casting to `float`?  Your column datatype can't be `float` and `nvarchar` at the same time, so even though you separate the two in your case, it will fail on the `ELSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for `try_convert()` instead of `isnumeric()`:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 0), Tbl1.Column1)),Tbl1.Column1) as Column1
```

A conversion problem arises with your approach because a `case` expression returns a single value.  One of the branches is numeric, so the return type is numeric -- and the conversion in the `else` fails.

You can fix your version by converting the `then` clause to a string after converting to a float.

Comment: is this sqlserver version specific ? I get `'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function name` in sql server 2014

Comment: I'm also using 14, being playing around with your coalesce however can't seem to get the syntax right with this statement

Comment: @dan6657 Try it now

Comment: I still get the same error 'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function

Comment: 'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function name.
is this a server 2017 function? - thanks for the syntax update aaron

Comment: Huh.. I must be overlooking something, I can copy paste that and it works.  Before, the parentheses were a little off, so it was reading the decimal part as a function.  It's not a function, it's part of `TRY_CONVERT`.  `TRY_CONVERT` is 2012+ I believe..

Comment: @dan6657 You may not be on 2014? Here is a sample: http://rextester.com/LJUY58009

Comment: The problem was the database compatibility level was less that SQL 2012. I fixed it with `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;`

Answer (score 2):

since you hold both types in this column, you need to cast your rounded value back to varchar

```
declare @Tbl1 table (Column1 varchar(10))

insert into @Tbl1 (Column1) values ('8.1'), ('2'), ('9.0'), 
                                   ('9.6'), ('A'), ('5.3'), 
                                   ('D'), ('E'), ('5.1'), ('-')

select case when TRY_CONVERT(float, Column1) IS NULL then Column1
            else cast(cast(Round(Column1, 0) as float) as varchar(10))
       end  AS 'Column1' 
from   @Tbl1
```

outcome is

```
Column1
-------
8
2   
9
10  
A   
5   
D   
E   
5   
-
```

In case you get the error `TRY_CONVERT`is not a build-in function then you have your database compatibility level is less that SQL 2012.

You can correct that using this command

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;
```

**Also note that after this statement the answer of Gordon is working now, and I agree that is a better answer then mine**

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still get the cast error with this case :[

Comment: copy / Paste the entire query and run it. Does it still gives an error ? It works on my database without error.

Comment: fair enough this does work, I will have a look at my query again.

Comment: or maybe you have other data in your table than in your sample that can cause this

Comment: ah, I have -'s where the value is null?

Comment: insert into @Tbl1 (Column1) values ('8.1'), ('2'), ('9.0'), ('9.6'), ('A'), ('5.3'), ('D'), ('E'), ('5.1'), ('-')

Comment: yes I get it to now with this value, let me work on this

Comment: I edited my answer it works again for me now, please try it again